# C type notation

Tags: c, types

I've always been slightly confused as to how C type notation works. I don't have access to Google, and Bing is turning up garbage results.

For example: what does `int *(*)[]` mean? I know already that it's a pointer to an array of integer pointers (I think), but why? In particular, I'm confused as to what the brackets are doing; yeah, `int **[]` would be an array of pointers to pointers, but why does `()` change that?

Comment: Try [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/): interactive fun with declarations.

Comment: ..and add an identifier in the middle, like `int *(*name)[]`

Comment: @KamilCuk oh, I don't mean in declarations. This is type notation that I've seen online lectures use, and those don't seem to ever associate specifics names with a type.

Comment: Which online lectures? How do they use it? Then are you _sure_ there is `[]` behind? Because `int *(*)[]` as is is invalid - there has to be a number inside `[]`. In general: Please give _context_ in which such expression is used?

Comment: Can be part of a function prototype: `void foo(int *(*)[]);`

Comment: @KamilCuk It's not invalid, it's a pointer to an array of incomplete type. There's even a few rare use-cases for such pointers: functions or macros taking generic-size arrays. Because an array of incomplete item type is compatible with a complete array of the same item type, and the same applies to pointers to them.

Comment: Take for example `#define IS_INT_ARRAY(x) _Generic(&(x), int(*)[]: true, default: false)`.

Comment: Yup, I've checked and apparently I was looking at fn prototypes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To read such types, mentally add a variable name to the expression to turn it into a valid declaration. Then read it from the inside out, like you read all variable declarations in C:

```
int **[]   ->   int **a[];

a[]         //[] has higher precedence than *, so `a` is an array
*a[]        //this array contains pointers
**a[]       //which dereference to pointers
int **a[];  //which dereference to int
```

So, `int**[]` is the type of an **array of pointers** to pointers to `int`.

With the other type, we get:

```
int *(*)[]   ->   int *(*a)[];

*a            //a is a pointer
(*a)          //(precedence control, only)
(*a)[]        //which dereferences to an array
*(*a)[]       //which contains pointers
int *(*a)[];  //which dereference to int
```

So, `int*(*)[]` is the type of a **pointer to an array** of pointers to `int`.

As you see, the parentheses have the effect of selecting the first `*` operator before the `[]`. The later has higher precedence, so if you need a pointer to an array, you need to introduce the parentheses.

---

There are three operators which are relevant to type declarations, and it's important to know their precedence:

```
High precedence:
[]    array subscript declares an array
()    function call declares a function

Low precedence:
*     dereference operator declares a pointer
```

Because the `*` has lower precedence than either `()` or `[]`, you need to add the extra parentheses to declare pointers to arrays or functions:

```
int *a[];    //array of pointers, as a cast: `(int*[])`
int (*a)[];  //pointer to an array, as a cast: `(int(*)[])`

int *a();    //function returning a pointer, as a cast: `(int*())`
int (*a)(); //pointer to a function returning an `int`, as a cast: `(int(*)())`
```

Once you've understood this principle, no type expression in C will confound you anymore.